# Lighthouse 'Issues' are nowhere to be found

Tags: html, lighthouse

So, I've been working to improve the Lighthouse score on my site. In Best Practices it says there are Issues logged but I can't see any in the Issues panel.

Is there an issue with Lighthouse? Am I looking in the wrong place? I can't find any information about this online.

Link to the site:
https://wordpress-617059-2002059.cloudwaysapps.com/

Screenshots of the mention of Issues and the issues panel.

[image]
[image]

Comment: check "include third-party cookie issues" - there are 8 there.

Comment: Glad that sorted it for you , if you need any help solving then let me know! (well ask a new question and I will answer )

Answer (score 1):

As per Graham's comment, should have checked the "include third-party cookie issues" to find them. Thanks again!